# Why do we study fermi system at half-filling state?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fermions, fermi-liquids

I am reading Shankar's paper on RG for interacting fermions and in the paper, all study is done on Fermi system at half-filling state. Is there any specific reason why? Also, does it make a different on physical system if one chooses to use Spinless Fermions so that the half-filling state is one fermion every other state or Fermions with spin degree of freedom so that the half-filling state now is one fermion every state?